# Get a single row element based on the text values of the children elements in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get a single row element based on the text values of the children in it? For example if I have the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="a">AA</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="a">AA</div>
    <div class="b">BB</div>
    <div class="c">CC</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="a">AAA</div>
    <div class="b">BB</div>
    <div class="c">CC</div>
</div>
```

How can I get the second row based on row having a child class 'a' div with AA and a class 'b' div with BB and a class 'c' div with CC?

```
var elem = $('.row'); // How can I get a particular row based on the text values of the children elements in it?
```

Comment: i think the answer still depend, if he wanted exact or just containing those words. but here i assume he wanted only the second row

Comment: Yeah, just the second row. I want the row that matches all criteria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in conjunction with [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
var elem = $('.row').filter(function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    var hasA = _this.has('div.a'); 
    var hasB = _this.has('div.b');
    var hasC = _this.has('div.c');

    if(hasA && hasB && hasC){
        return _this.find('div.a').text().trim() == 'AA'
            && _this.find('div.b').text().trim() == 'BB'
            && _this.find('div.c').text().trim() == 'CC'
    }

    return false;   
});
```

As requested

```
function getElements(valueForA, valueForB, valueForC){
    return $('.row').filter(function(){
        var _this = $(this);
        var hasA = _this.has('div.a'); 
        var hasB = _this.has('div.b');
        var hasC = _this.has('div.c');

        if(hasA && hasB && hasC){
            return _this.find('div.a').text().trim() == valueForA
                && _this.find('div.b').text().trim() == valueForB
                && _this.find('div.c').text().trim() == valueForC
        }

        return false;   
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Could you write it as a function which takes in the 'AA', 'BB', 'CC' values and returns the row?

Comment: Awesome. I'll select yours as the answer right after I try it out.

Comment: `hasb` variable should be `hasB` and having two delcaration

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:contains` selector for such kind of requests:

https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

So something like:

```
$('div.b:contains("AA")')
```

This should return all matches, then you can take whichever you want from it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use contains selector:

```
$('div:contains("AA")').parent()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can use the :contains

$('div.a:contains("AA")')

$('div.b:contains("BB")')

$('div.c:contains("CC")')
```